# Coffeescript translation - nested for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, coffeescript

I'm trying to learn javascript in coffeescript, and am practicing by rewriting some neat javascript on codepen. Something's gone wrong, and I think it'd due to my ignorance of how to write a nested loop in coffee script. The original code is:

```
for(var j = 0 ; j<yElems;j++){
  for(var i = 0 ; i<xElems;i++){

var elem = document.createElement('div');

if(i%2==0){
  elem.classList.add('bs');
}else{
  elem.classList.add('bs1');
}

elem.style.top = j*30-20+'px';    
elem.style.left = i*30-20+'px';    
elem.style.zIndex =100- j+''+i;
elem.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.round(Math.random()*4)];
body.appendChild(elem); 
elems.push(elem);
 }
}
```

and my 'translation' is:

```
grid = -> 
  for i in xElems
    elem = document.createElement 'div'
    if i % 2 is 0 then elem.classList.add 'bs' else elem.classList.add 'bs1'
    elem.style.top = j*30-20+'px'   
    elem.style.left = i*30-20+'px'    
    elem.style.zIndex = 100- j+''+i
    elem.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.round(Math.random()*4)]
    body.appendChild(elem)
    elems.push(elem)

for j in yElems
  grid()
```

Not sure what's not working. And if it's not that, i'm still not sure. The original pen is at:

http://codepen.io/pixelgrid/pen/Hxkhs

and my fork is:

http://codepen.io/bubbaJackson/pen/tyLGC

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in xElems
```

should be

```
for i in [0..xElems] by 1
```

The same should be done for the j loop as well.

i in xElems will try to treat xElems as an array and give you each element in the array.  xElems appears to be a number in the original js, and so you want to iterate over a range, which you can do by using the `[a..b]` notation.  Note that `[a..b]` will exclude b, while `[a...b]` will include the value of b.

#### Update

As `mu is too short` points out in the comments, this compiles directly to basically what you were trying to copy: `for(i = 0; i < xElems; ++i)`

Comment: I think it is worth noting that this form of `for` is compiled to a simple `for(i = 0; i < xElems; ++i)` loop, CoffeeScript won't bother creating an array for the range.

Comment: sure. The point is that it can't do anything with the original syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not criticizing, that's just an FYI comment.

Comment: thanks, not sure i grasp this last bit or why an array is needed. I inserted the new bits, but it's not working yet. I'm still scratching my head wondering why. Is it possible to directly nest the for loop after the other for loop in coffeescript?

Comment: Sure.  If you need help understanding I would take some time to look at the JavaScript that is outputed when the file is compiled.  The array is needed because the `in` operator iterates over an array.  It won't be valid with a number argument.